# Are Rsnapshot backups self contained - how to save into zip?

Tags: centos, rsync, backup, rsnapshot

I have some old backups done by [rsnapshot](https://rsnapshot.org/). The directories are:

```
/backups/week.0
/backups/week.1
/backups/week.2
/backups/week.3
/backups/week.4
```

I'd like to keep only one copy and delete the others. Since the backups are incremental, will it work if I zipped `week.0` into `week.0.zip`and deleted everything else?

Answer (score 0):

Zip should work.

By default zip seems to be "compressing and storing the files referred to by the (symbolic) link".

The opposite would be to use the `--symlinks` switch.

```
   --symlinks
              For  UNIX  and  VMS (V8.3 and later), store symbolic links as such in
              the zip archive, instead of compressing and storing the file referred
              to  by  the  link.  This can avoid multiple copies of files being in‐
              cluded in the archive as zip recurses the  directory  trees  and  ac‐
              cesses files directly and by links.
```

Comment: By default, rsnapshot uses hard links rather than symbolic links.  That means it doesn't matter if your zip program understands symbolic links or not -- it'll store the actual files either way.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you really need to use a ZIP format archive, the native solution tends to be with `tar`:

```
tar cf week.0.tar week.0
```

However, by default the result isn't compressed so you would need to specify that, or pipe the output through a compressor. These two commands are equivalent:

```
tar czf week.0.tgz week.0
tar czf - week.0 | gzip >week.0.tgz
```

Replace `c` (Create) with `x` (eXtract) or `t` (lisT). Newer versions of `tar` may also support stronger compression than `gzip`.